# Difference in Run & Debugg mode in Eclipse for Perl

Tags: eclipse, perl

I am using Eclipse along with EPIC plug in and pad walker for running my Perl project.
I am facing a strange issue

If I "Run" the project, the system fails and exits Perl without any error message.
But if I "Debug" the project and then give "Run" the same Perl scripts work fine as expected.

Could anyone let me know the difference in the two mode ("Direct Run" & "Debug & Run")?

Answer (score 0):

[Found it](http://e-p-i-c.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/e-p-i-c/org.epic.debug/src/org/epic/debug/local/LocalLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java?view=markup#l117) in the EPIC source code: EPIC adds the "-d" command line option for the debug target.  It does some interesting things with the stdin/stdout too to remotely control the debugger.  So maybe there's some side effect there?  Can you share the error message?

Comment: There was actual no error message, but the script wasn't executed. I have a script that would communicate with micro controller debugger. It worked fine without any error under debug mode. But if I run the same script, it exits the Perl without any error message or warning.